# Добавление/перезапись параметра в файл.properties

Tags: java, файлы, config

У меня есть две программы на java. Первая авторизуется продавцом и создаёт в магазине товар. Вторая авторизуется покупателем и покупает его.

Интересует, как правильно в первой программе записать/перезаписать параметр в файл `config.properties` чтобы во второй считать его .

Я умею только писать конфиг руками и считывать из него параметры, или создавать динамический, но он живёт пока работает программа, а мне нужно считать параметр при выполнении другой программы.

Прошу не предлагать мне изменить архитектуру приложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обмен информацией при помощи properties файлов не очень хорошая идея. В большинстве случаев они должны быть строго **read-only**.
Для вашего случая скорее подойдет база данных, например [`h2`](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). Но если так хочется, то можете создать файл, например так:

```
Path path = Paths.get("config.xml")
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("key", "value");
properties.storeToXML(Files.newOutputStream(path),"this is very important file");
```

А прочитать параметры так:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.loadFromXML(Files.newInputStream(path));

System.out.println(properties.getProperty("key"));
```

> value

**PS** если использовать  методы `store` и `load` соотвественно, то файл будет иметь структуру `properties` файла, а не `xml` как в примере